# Why PyImport_ImportModule returns a PyObject* with a refcount of 3 instead of 1

Tags: python, c++

I'm working with Python C API in my C++ program and I've noticed an odd thing.

While running a simple program like this in my debugger on my PC:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* scipy_stats_module = PyImport_ImportModule("scipy.stats"); // importing "scipy.stats" module

    Py_DecRef(scipy_stats_module);

    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        PyErr_Print();
        exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I've seen that the `ob_refcnt` attribute of `scipy_stats_module`, right after its creation and before calling `Py_DecRef`, is set at 3 while I was expecting it to be equal to 1.

Can somebody help me understand why is this happening? Is this a problem with my code or is it normal? Should I call `Py_DecRef` three times or just once?

Thank you!

P.S. I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 as IDE and debugger on my PC with macOS 10.12.5

Comment: One reference is stored in `sys.modules` dict after a module is imported (caching). But I'm not sure where the other comes from.

Comment: @freakish Ok, so it's not a problem with my code I suppose. But should I call `Py_DecRef` 3 times every time I use `PyImport` or something similar like `PyObject_GetAttrString` then? It seems odd to me.

Comment: I don't think so. You should only call `Py_DecRef` once. After you've done working with it. `Py_Finalize` should take care of the rest. But perhaps you should wait for someone else to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't own the only reference to the new module. While in this case, it's simple to identify the other references - one is `sys.modules['scipy.stats']`, and one is the `stats` attribute of the `scipy` module object - in general, it's not your concern what other references a module might have.

When you clear your reference to the module, you should only `Py_DECREF` once, because you're only clearing one reference, the one you own. The other references still exist and still need to be accounted for in the refcount.